# How does Intel's CRC algorithm use polynomial multiplication to maintain congruence?

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

[This white paper](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/fast-crc-computation-generic-polynomials-pclmulqdq-paper.pdf) shows a method of computing a CRC much faster than table lookup for any polynomial. When I read further to see how it works, the authors write the following (emphasis mine):

> For any application that requires CRC one can **pre-compute a few constants (that are a function of the polynomial)** and then **repeatedly apply** these constants to fold the most-significant chunks of the data buffer, at each stage **creating a new buffer that is smaller in length but congruent (modulo the polynomial) to the original one**, as illustrated in Figure 2.

Looking at the assembly shown in the paper shows that it involves multiplying and adding polynomials in $\text{GF}(2)$. What are these constants, and what does the "repeated application" of said constants mean? I'd like to see how this arises, however, I don't know too much about finite fields.

Comment: this doesn't seem to be specific to intel's implementation - are you just generally asking about how to find adequate polynomials for CRCs?

Comment: No, I'm asking about how carry-less multiplication (i.e. GF(2) polynomial multiplication) is used in this specific algorithm to reduce the message while maintaining its congruence to the generator polynomial.

Comment: Could you very precisely pinpoint which multiplication you mean? I'm honestly a bit confused about which part you're wondering.

Comment: I've just rewritten the question to be more clear.